# Quaternion slerp with shortest path not working

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, quaternions

My slerp routine is below.  From what I've read, the check against > 0 should handle it so it always takes the shortest path.  But it never does.  In the case where I cross a "pole", the quaternion flips out and produces angles with NAN values.

```
quat quat::slerp(quat dest, float t)
{
  const quat &from = *this;
  static const double epsilon = 0.0001;
  double theta, cosTheta, sinTheta;
  double p, q;

  cosTheta = from.x*dest.x + from.y*dest.y + from.z*dest.z + from.w*dest.w;

  if(cosTheta < 0.0)
  {
    dest = { -from.x, -from.y, -from.z, -from.w };
    cosTheta = -cosTheta;
  }

  if((1.0-fabs(cosTheta)) > epsilon)
  {
    theta = acos(cosTheta);
    sinTheta = sin(theta);
    q = sin((1-t) * theta) / sinTheta;
    p = sin(t*theta) / sinTheta;
  }
  else
  {
    q = 1-t;
    p = t;
  }

  quat qo;
  qo.w = (float)((q * from.w) + (p * dest.w));
  qo.x = (float)((q * from.x) + (p * dest.x));
  qo.y = (float)((q * from.y) + (p * dest.y));
  qo.z = (float)((q * from.z) + (p * dest.z));

  return qo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are other bugs as well, but this line certainly has one:

```
dest = { -from.x, -from.y, -from.z, -from.w };
```

It overwrites `dest` with `-from`, which is not correct. It should be:

```
dest = { -dest.x, -dest.y, -dest.z, -dest.w };
```

Comment: Jesus...  yea that's prob it.  Let me fix that.